# Benefits of transforming/scaling target variable in supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, normal-distribution

I'm learning about how helpful it is to have your variables in a gaussian distribution. It's not very clear to me how to apply this to a supervised learning problem, say, using a neural network. The following is the target variable for my dataset, the sqrt and log of the target variable respectively.

[image]

## Question

Is there any benefit/point is transforming a continuous target variable in a regression problem?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes. Some algorithms, for ex. ANN, work with gradients, and in this case having a better behaving variable works in favor of the optimization. However, other times, for ex. with linear models, scaling won't affect the model fit.

A lot of people unnecessarily transform their variables to be normal because of a false belief that this will improve the model. Unless the method requires normal data, or the optimization algorithm will work better because of it, this belief is unfounded.